# Matching two files and keeping blocks that contain the match

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

I have two files and I am trying to match them and to keep whole blocks from `file1` (`matched` and `unmatched` elements), but to change filenames of the elements that are beeing matched.

`File1`:

```
3L21_NAJOX  Naja oxiana P01382  PDB; 1NTN; X-ray; 1.90 A; A=1-73.
                                PDB; 1W6B; NMR; -; A=1-73.

3LKB_BUNMU  Bungarus multicinctus   P01398  PDB; 1KBA; X-ray; 2.30 A; A/B=22-87.
                                            PDB; 2NBT; NMR; -; A/B=22-87.

3NOJ_BUNCA  Bungarus candidus   P81782  PDB; 1F94; X-ray; 0.97 A; A=1-63.
                                        PDB; 1IJC; NMR; -; A=1-63.
```

The column that is just after `PDB;` is what I am matching.

The `file2` is a list of names (the first four letters are important):

```
1KBA_GAL.pdb
1A3L_CFC.pdb
1F94_.pdb
1A3U_.pdb
1A3V_.pdb
1A4H_.pdb
```

So I am trying to match names (the first four letters) from the second file with the names that are appearing just after the `PDB;` column in the first file. If the name in the element from the `file1` matches one in the second file, then keep the whole block (either `matched` and `unmatched` elements), but replace the names of the elements in the `file1`, with the elements from the `file2`

So from this example, the output I want is:

```
3LKB_BUNMU  Bungarus multicinctus   P01398  PDB; 1KBA_GAL; X-ray; 2.30 A; A/B=22-87.
                                            PDB; 2NBT; NMR; -; A/B=22-87

3NOJ_BUNCA  Bungarus candidus   P81782  PDB; 1F94_; X-ray; 0.97 A; A=1-63.
                                        PDB; 1IJC; NMR; -; A=1-63.
```

Does anybody have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok lets try this little script I conjured up:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

match1=/home/george/Documents/askubuntu/matchme/match1
match2=/home/george/Documents/askubuntu/matchme/match2

# Create the result file
touch results.txt

while read -r word
do
     if [[ "$word" = $(grep -o "$word" "$match1") ]]; then
             if [[ "$word" != $(grep -o "$word" "results.txt") ]]
             then
                     grep "$(grep "$word" "$match1" | grep -o "[[:digit:]]..$")" "$match1" >> "results.txt"
                     while read -r new
                     do                                 
                             if [[ "$new" =~ $word ]]; then
                                     # Replace the words
                                     sed -i "s/$word/$new/" "results.txt"
                             fi
                     done < <(grep  -o "$word_.*\." "$match2" | sed -e 's/\.//')
                     # Add space between results
                     echo " " >> "results.txt"
             fi
     fi
done < <(cut -d"_" -f1 "$match2")

# Remove last blank line from the results file
sed -i '$ d' results.txt
```

Explanation:

- `match1`: contains the filter source
- `match2`: contains the filter criteria
- `set -e`: stop script is error occurs
- `(grep  -o "$word_.*\." "$match2" | sed -e 's/\.//')`: read the filter file and grab the names up to the `pdb` extension

Description of the command process:

1. Using `cut` command get the filter criteria from file `match2` (1KBA,1A3L, ,1F94, 1A3U, 1A3V, 1A4H), then
2. Read from the `cut` command result and find matches in the sources file `match1`,
3. If a match is found `grep` for that block in the source file and send or print to a new file `result.txt`

**NOTE:**
Please modify names and other parameters to your taste.

**RESULTS:**

```
$cat results.txt 
3LKB_BUNMU  Bungarus multicinctus   P01398  PDB; 1KBA_GAL; X-ray; 2.30 A; A/B=22-87.
                                        PDB; 2NBT; NMR; -; A/B=22-87.

3NOJ_BUNCA  Bungarus candidus   P81782  PDB; 1F94_; X-ray; 0.97 A; A=1-63.
                                    PDB; 1IJC; NMR; -; A=1-63.
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73941/discussion-on-answer-by-george-udosen-matching-two-files-and-keeping-blocks-that).

Comment: hey, a bit strange but script compiles good on this example and fufills the logic described, but when I run it on larger dataset like..50 blocks it doesn't compiles correctly in terms; it doesn't replace names from `file 2` and it deletes unmatched lines. If u have some time duriing the day may I sent u somewhere these a bit bigger data to check what seems to be wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using `awk` in *paragraph mode* e.g.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {
       sub(/_[^_]*$/,"",$1); a[$1]++; next
     } 
     {
       for (x in a) {
         if ($0 ~ "PDB; "x) {print; break;}
       }
     }' file2 RS= file1
```

Ex.:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {sub(/_[^_]*$/,"",$1); a[$1]++; next} {for (x in a) {if ($0 ~ "PDB; "x) {print; break;}}}' file2 RS= file1
3LKB_BUNMU  Bungarus multicinctus   P01398  PDB; 1KBA; X-ray; 2.30 A; A/B=22-87.
                                            PDB; 2NBT; NMR; -; A/B=22-87.
3NOJ_BUNCA  Bungarus candidus   P81782  PDB; 1F94; X-ray; 0.97 A; A=1-63.
                                        PDB; 1IJC; NMR; -; A=1-63.
```

---

If you want a blank line after each block, you can change `{print; break;}`to `{print $0"\n"; break;}` or `{printf "%s\n\n", $0; break}` although note that this will add a trailing blank line after the last record where there may not have been one originally - if you have GNU awk (`gawk`) you can avoid that by accessing the special variable `RT` which contains the actual separator for each record i.e. `{printf "%s%s", $0, RT; break;}`

Comment: Thanks, this is very effective script. Just one question, can it be changed so that when matching this `four letter/digit elements` between these two files, output (result) file has matched and unmatched elements (like output from your script has) but to keep this filenames from second file in the output (so instead of `1KBA.pdb` to have `1KBA_GAL.pdb`)?